# Overloading << for a string class

Tags: c++, string

I have:

```
String8& operator<<(const String8& string2);
```

For this:

```
String8 s;
s << "533";
```

But I would like to do this:

```
String8* s;
s << "433";
```

Without having to do `* s << "433";` or `String8&`.  `String8* operator<<(const String8& string2);` doesn't appear to work.  I tried making it a global operator overload too...

Any ideas?

Here is the full code with the operator as global:

```
class String8 
{
    public:
        String8(char array[]) { }
};

String8* operator<<(String8* string1, const String8& string2);

main()
{
    String8* s;
    s << "433"
}
```

Compiler error:C2296: '<<' : illegal, left operand has type 'Base::String8 *'

Answer (score 2):

You need to make it a non-member function and take a `String8*` as the first parameter:

```
String8* operator<<(String8* target, const String8& string2);
```

BTW, this seems like a rather questionable thing to do just to spare yourself a single asterisk.

Comment: And make it a non-member function.

Comment: Like this? String8* operator<<(String8* string1, const String8& string2);  I'm doing something wrong...

Comment: @RyanBrown: Did you move it outside the class's definition?

Comment: yes, that one is global.  I'm trying lots of different things here and nothing seems to work

Comment: @RyanBrown: Dunno. Amend the question with the modified code and the error your getting.

Comment: Do you think it would be counterintuitive to do '<<' to a String8 pointer?  Maybe...

Comment: @RyanBrown A string literal is a `const char[]`, not a `char[]`. The constructor of `String8` should be changed to reflect that. And yes, it is counterintuitive.

Comment: @RyanBrown: Yes it is counterintuitive to most C++ developers. It is just a convention to use references, so I'm not saying don't do it, but you need to ask yourself whether the benefits you are hoping for outweigh the confusion it will cause other programmers reading the code later on. You also need to consider whether it makes sense to pass a null pointer, which is allowed for pointers, but not allowed (indeed, meaningless) for references.

Comment: @RyanBrown also your `main` is missing a return type. And apparently C++ doesn't try conversions when looking for an operator to use, so you can't do this (without modification) anyway.